# Design a Android custom layout equivalent for IOS

Tags: ios, user-interface

Coming from Android, I'm trying to learn coding on IOS, and it's really confusing.
What I'm trying to achieve is a scrollview that include a dynamic number of textfields.

You can add a textfield by pressing the plus button and remove the field by pressing the minus corresponding minus button.

But I have no clue about the best design for that. Can you give a lead ?

Something like:

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Make a custom UITableViewCell that has a UITextField in it.

Comment: Insert picture in your question itself. All users may not have access to external links.

Comment: @Error404 not all users have permission to insert photos. Never mind, I added for OP.

Comment: @BackPapp There are a lot of ways to do so. what Dan suggest is a possible way, but lots of text field in same page sound not a good idea for user experience sake, especially when keyboard appears.

Comment: I'll go with a top textfield and a tableview below. Does that sound ok ? What I don't get is if I should put everything in a single viewController or I should add a tableviewcontroller as a child of the mainviewCOntroller.

Comment: Well @Raptor, I just wanted to inform what I have learnt till now, that, external links are not preferred and the relevant information or image should be added in the question itself. Thanks anyways!